# Can I use multithreading to make the same rest call mutiple times at once?

Tags: java, multithreading, rest

I am using java and going to do some rest calls using Zephyr's api. I don't think the the api used will affect the possibility of my question.  I was just wondering if it is possible make the same rest call multiple times at the same time using multithreading? Each call would be retrieving different data, they are not all grabbing the same data.

This is just strictly for retrieving data, not writing.

If this is possible, what are the risks? Is this recommended?

Comment: You web app will already be multithreaded by virtue of the fact that it is deployed in a web server. Every client issuing a call will be done on a per thread basis by the web server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For sure, it will improve your performance if you implement it the right way. As mentioned, you just need to be careful with the implementation to avoid security and performance issues. I'd suggest to have a thread pool, so you can manage many threads that are performing the REST calls you're doing at the same time.

`ThreadPoolExecutor` will be helpful.

You can use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`/`Executors.newCachedThreadPool`. Both of them works fine.

You can create a task (implementing `Callable`) to perform your REST invokation or call, and then use the `invokeAll(`) of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` (You would like to include the list of the tasks here).

Hope it helps you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, yes, this is doable, but you should be aware of the possible load you'd be putting on the server.

One solution I've used for that sort of thing in the past is a work queue of one sort or another. For example:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS);

for (final Thing thing : things) {
    es.submit(new Runnable {
        @Override
        void run() {
            doSomething(thing);
        }
    });
}

es.shutdown();
```

What this does:

1. Uses [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) to create a new [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) that will handle up to `MAX_THREADS` tasks in parallel.
2. Iterates over a list of "things" to work on (whatever those are is going to be domain-dependent), and creates a new anonymous `Runnable` class to call `doSomething(thing)` on each of those. Here's where you'd make your calls to the server and do whatever work you had to do.
3. Calls [`ExecutorService.shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) to tell the `ExecutorService` that we've finished giving it things to do. If you want to wait for all those tasks to finish, see [`ExecutorService#awaitTermination(long, TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

See also: [Thread Pools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Just be careful about how many times you call it, because you will exceed the session limit of your server depending of your server parameter. Also if you call it with a lot of thread and rapidly, you will probably get something that looks like a denial of service attack.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. Even writing data shouldn't be a problem. The only risks is that you could overload your data connection(s) a lot faster or that your server may not allow this. The other risks are inherent to doing multithreading badly.